# My AsyncTask runs even when its if statement conditions aren't met

Tags: android, asynchronous, dialog, onclick, execute

I want to display an alert dialog and get the user input on whether or not to run the AsyncTask. However the AsyncTask runs anyway, even when I put it in an if statement. Does anyone know why this is happening? This is my code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Boolean b = false;

            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ThisScreen.this);
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            b = true;
                        }
                    });
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            b = false;
                        }
                    });

            alertbox.setTitle("Title");
            alertbox
                    .setMessage("Continue?");
            alertbox.show();

            if(b)
                new doAsyncTask().execute;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it makes any difference but the logical thing would be to set the no-button using the method setNegativeButton().

Comment: This does work, however, I want to prompt the user about something if necessary. For example: if the user didn't input vital information I will show the alert dialog and ask them if they want to run the asynctask anyway. If they did input all information, I don't want the AlertDialog to pop up at all. Which means I need an if statement, which means back to square one. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ok, it seems that when I put the task into the else part of the if staement, it follows the conditions. However just putting it in the if part with no else and it runs regardless. This solves my problem, but it may not for other people. Thanks. This is a weird little bug.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code to run the task inside

```
alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            runMyDoAsyncTask(); // <-- here
        }
    });
```

btw I'm not sure that the code you provided will ever compile :)

Comment: I have tried this too, but I am still getting the same results. have you got any other ideas?

Comment: I took working code, and changed the variable names. Maybe I accidentally changed something, but what do you think is wrong?

Comment: @TehGoose you have local variable `b` which is accessed from inner class and not declared `final` which should trigger compilation error

Comment: I was expecting that too when writing it, but it compiles and runs without a hitch.